# Using a list of data frames to create loop that makes changes to each data frame in the list

Tags: r

I am currently working on  about 30+ data frames. Here is just a glimpse of the code:

```
for (i in list1){
attach(i)
i$p_change = i$prem_dist_TY - i$prem_dist_LY
detach(i)
}
```

`p_change` is the new variable i would like to added to all dataframes in `list1`

`prem_dist_TY` and `prem_dist_LY` are variables that already exist in all the dataframes in `list1`
This function seems to run, but there is no new variable create in the dataframes.

Please suggest ways i can do this.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done more easily without `attach` by looping over the `list` with `lapply`, and use `transform` to create the new column, assign (`<-`) back to the original object

```
list1 <- lapply(list1, transform, p_change = prem_dist_TY - prem_dist_LY)
```

If it is a named `list`, and wanted the objects created in the global env i.e. the names of the list to change as well (not recommended), use `list2env`

```
list2env(list1, .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Or in a `for` loop, loop over the sequence of the `list` and do the assignment on the same `list` element by creating a new column with the difference of the columns

```
for(i in seq_along(list1)) list1[[i]][["p_change"]] <-
           with(list1[[i]], prem_dist_TY - prem_dist_LY)
```

---

or with `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
list1 <- map(list1, ~ .x %>%
                  mutate(p_change = prem_dist_TY - prem_dist_LY))
```

Comment: The code seems to be working, the problem I am facing now is that I use the following list also to generate an excel workbook with all the data frames. And when I do that sheet names are coming as Sheet1, sheet2, sheet3. i need the names to be df1, df2, df3, df4,. Earlier, I was using the following list to generate excel sheet. :
`list_of_df <- list("df1"=df1,"df2"=df2,"df3"=df3)

write.xlsx(list_of_df,path)`
the above the code makes changes to df in the list on global environment. But in order to make the excel sheet using, I would need df on my global environment to change

Comment: @NikhilKakdiya What are the names of `list`? The first code is just updating the `list`.  If there are already names, then it will not having any problem.   or you can change the names with `names(list1) <- paste0("df", seq_along(list1))`

Comment: the changes are not really coming along! i didn't understand the new part you added. It gives an error:  names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x

Comment: @NikhilKakdiya I assume the `names(list1)` are `'df1', 'df2', ....  Then the changes would reflect when you do `list2env(list1, .GlobalEnv)` and then check `df1`, `df2` etc

Comment: What about `list1 %>% set_names() %>% map(~ mutate(.x, p_change = prem_dist_TY - prem_dist_LY))`